# У меня есть задание с операторами JOIN не уверена что верно выполняю запрос

Tags: sql

Вот условие.  Найти имена клиентов (CustomerName), кто размещал более одного заказа за день. Вывести имена (CustomerName), айдишники кастомеров, а также дату и точное кол-во заказов за день.

Вот Мой запрос:

```sql
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Customers.CustomerID, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers. CustomerName = Orders.OrderDate
```

Не совсем понимаю как вывести точное кол-во заказов за день.

Comment: *Не совсем понимаю как вывести точное кол-во заказов за день.* А как вообще считают количество? в запросах есссно.

Comment: *Вот Мой запрос* Вы можете объяснить, почему использовано именно левое связывание?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так найдёте кол-во заказов за день для каждого клиента, соединять таблицы надо обычным JOIN:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, o.day, o.order_count
FROM Customers c
JOIN (
  SELECT CustomerID, TRUNC(OrderDate) day, COUNT(*) order_count
  FROM Orders
  GROUP BY CustomerID, TRUNC(OrderDate)
) o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
```